# init method of a Serlvet without ServletException

Tags: java, exception, servlets

Though ServletException is a checked exception, I am able create a Servlet by extending HttpServlet and creating a init method with out throwing or catching the ServletException. The compiler didn't complain and the Servlet works as well.

How come this works.

Comment: Show us what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[One of the rules for overriding is that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1)

> The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA.

where [`subsignature`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) is defined as

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they
>   have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and,
>   after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type
>   parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a
>   method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.

So a `throws` clause can be ignored in the child class. However, [given `m2` overrides `m1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)

> - If m2 has a throws clause that mentions any checked exception types,
>     then m1 must have a throws clause, or a compile-time error occurs.
> - For every checked exception type listed in the throws clause of m2,
>     that same exception class or one of its supertypes must occur in the
>     erasure (§4.6) of the throws clause of m1; otherwise, a compile-time
>     error occurs.

Take the example

```
class Bar {
   public void method() throws Exception {}
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    @Override  
    public void method() {}
}
```

If you do

```
Bar bar = new Foo();
bar.method(); // you'll need to handle it, but it will never happen

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.method(); // you don't need to handle, it still won't ever happen
```

But the inverse

```
class Bar {
   public void method() throws SomeCheckedException{}
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    @Override  
    public void method() throws SomeOtherUnrelatedCheckedException{}
}
```

would fail

```
Bar bar = new Foo();
bar.method(); // Bar says some exception can happen, but the actual object may throw another, it wouldn't be handled.
```

Answer (score 1):

When a method is declared with

```
throws ServletException
```

That doesn't mean that it **must** throw a ServletException. That means that it **may** throw a ServletException. So, if your method never throws a ServletException, that's fine. What wouldn't be fine is if your `init()` method threw a checked exception of another type than ServletException..